# search between 2 different dates with laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I can currently search for an article and a date that I am looking for. How could I do the same but search for an article between 2 dates

Let's think that criterion 1 is the name field, criterion is created_at, how could you add criterion 2 to be able to search between 2 dates

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    if (!$request->ajax()) return redirect('/');

    $buscar1 = $request->buscar1;
    $criterio1 = $request->criterio1;
    $buscar = $request->buscar;
    $criterio = $request->criterio;
  
    
    if ($buscar==''){
        $historial = Historial::orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(10);
    }
    else{
        $historial = Historial::where($criterio1, 'like', '%'. $buscar1 . '%')
        ->where($criterio, 'like', '%'. $buscar . '%')
        
        ->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(10);
    }

  listarHistorial (page,buscar1,criterio1,buscar,criterio){
     let me=this;
     var url= this.ruta + '/historial?page=' + page + '&buscar1='+ buscar1 + '&criterio1='+ criterio1 + '&buscar='+ buscar + '&criterio='+ criterio;
            axios.get(url).then(function (response) {
                var respuesta= response.data;
                me.arrayHistorial = respuesta.historial.data;
                me.pagination= respuesta.pagination;
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
        }



   <select class="form-control col-md-6" v-model="criterio1">
  <option value="nombre">Nombre</option>
   </select>                                    
  <input type="date" v-model="buscar1" class="form-control;col-md-3" >

  <select class="form-control col-md-6" v-model="criterio">
                                  
   <option value="created_at">Fecha a Buscar</option>
    
   </select>
                               
<input type="date" v-model="buscar"  class="form-control;col-md-3" >
                                
<button type="submit" @click="listarHistorial(1,buscar1,criterio1,buscar,criterio)" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> Buscar</button>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: what about `...->whereBetween('created_at', [start,end])` you can add those as many as you want if we talking about periods also simple `->where(... , '<=', ...)` would work too if you want change signs, same add as many as you want

Comment: did not understand how vuejs is involved in your question

Comment: Thanks for the observation. I don't really understand how I could implement criterion 2 
with whereBetwwen

Comment: Please give specific question what is criterion 2 and from what it consists, like if you have 2 dates according to which you want to query data or what

Comment: Look how I do my search, how could it be between the 2 dates, 
add more code

Comment: is criterion and criterion 1, there are 2 input type day

Comment: Ok `Historial::whereDate($criterio1, '=', $buscar1 )
        ->whereDate($criterio, '=', $buscar)
        ->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(10);` or `>= =< > <` any sign that you want filter, you cant just take by date with sql like method using eloquent, you should use compare signs or equal

Comment: it didn't work with this Historial::whereDate($criterio1, '=', $buscar1 )         ->whereDate($criterio, '=', $buscar)         ->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(10)

Comment: I thought i explained it as easy as it can be i guess you just want answer without any practical help `whereDate($criterio1, '>=', $buscar1 )         ->whereDate($criterio, '=<', $buscar)`

Comment: I uploaded an image of how the search was carried out, however it gives me an error and does not give me any data

Comment: Which error specify, do you have data for this period show here

Comment: yes, I have data

Comment: I have added the code that executes my button method

Comment: query is correct the one i offered you it is the problem in js side you didn't parsed it right...use console log and debug your code

Comment: I already did it, but it does not mark any error

Comment: I uploaded a new image

Comment: Actually, you don't explain yourself. Better ask on Stackoverflow Español and I will answer your question there.

Comment: I have already posted in Spanish, hopefully you can help me. thank you. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/384071/realizar-busqueda-en-un-lapso-de-tiempo-laravel

Answer (score 1):

Try like below.

```
Query 1:
$historial = Historial::where($criterio1, 'like', '%'. $buscar1 . '%')
        ->where($criterio, 'like', '%'. $buscar . '%')
        ->whereBetween('created_at', [$request->get('date_from'), ])
        ->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(10);

Query 2:
$historial = Historial::where($criterio1, 'like', '%'. $buscar1 . '%')
        ->where($criterio, 'like', '%'. $buscar . '%')
        ->whereDate('created_at', '>=', $request->get('date_from') )
        ->whereDate('created_at', '<=', $request->get('date_to') )
        ->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(10);
```

Comment: Look how I do my search, how could it be between the 2 dates, 
add more code

Comment: what do you meant by two dates? do you meant $from_date and $to_date on a database field like created_at or you meant two different database fields? please explain. I will update my code according to your need.

Comment: it's just a created_at field

Comment: How could I use criteria and criteria 1 instead of date_from and date_to

Comment: I have put it, but it gives me an error when executing the search :(